# OTF font does not work, but ttf does

Tags: css, font-face

I have a problem with setting a font with a css.

Currently I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('_layouts/Fonts/myfont.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

And it does not apply my font to style, but if i change that to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('_layouts/Fonts/testfont.ttf') format("opentype");
}
```

(even if I left opentype as format), it does work.

Of course in a style i have added:

```
font-family: 'myfont';
```

Does anybody know this problem?

Comment: you need different font types for different browsers, if you have the ttf font you can use [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create the other fonts if you have permission

Comment: are you saying that you don't have TTF file present and the browser still renders it correctly?

Comment: The problem is probably in the .otf file or in the way you refer to it (e.g., whether it is in the correct directory). The problem is unanalyzable without further information, such as the origin of the font and the tools that were used to generate the font files.

Comment: I have checked it on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I have 2 fonts in same directory: myfont.otf and testfont.ttf, but setting otf font does not work, and ttf does

Comment: So what is the difference between those files? How were they produced, and can they be accessed online somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need four versions of the same font (eot, ttf, otf and woff) loading for crossbrowsing optimization. you probably don't see the .otf one because your browser doesn't support it (that's why you need 4).

i suggest you use google fonts, it's easy, quick and it just works: https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: Google docs does not contain font that i need unfortunately ;(

Comment: So what was the problem, and what was the solution? What might be the difference in font support to TTF vs OTF? Cf. http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf

Comment: I have used fontsquirel to generate fonts and used multiple formats in @font-face